# C# DateTimePicker comparison issue

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I want to compare the two dateTimePickers in the winforms using C#.

My comparing code is as below;

```
if (dtpFromDate.Value > dtpToDate.Value)
{
   MessageBox.Show("From Date is greater than To Date");
   return;
}
```

Below are the values of the two dateTimePickers

> dtpFromDate.Value = 10/29/2016 5:10:27 PM
>
> dtpToDate.Value   = 10/29/2016 5:10:27 PM

But if the two dateTimePickers are set to be at their initial values (i.e. today's date) as above, the if statement got also true, but what I need is to check only if the dates are greater (FromDate>ToDate). **Am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: Although they seem equal (in their string representation) the two DateTime Values may differ in seconds or milliseconds, if they are initialized with DateTime.Now. If you want to compare the dates you can use ´dtpFromDate.Value.Date > dtpToDate.Value.Date´

Comment: Try to do a _Console.WriteLine(dtpFromDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")_ and the same for the other dtp. You will see the difference

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care the time, do that:

```
if (dtpFromDate.Value.Date > dtpToDate.Value.Date)
{
   MessageBox.Show("From Date is greater than To Date");
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be explicit here, the data type of `dtpFromDate.Value` is of `DateTime`. I always prefer to use `DateTime.Tick` property for `DateTime` comparisons, since it is an integral type, so the comparison is obvious to the reader and also fast.

I believe when the two different `DateTimePicker` controls are created, they differ in their values by less than a second, causing the issue. If your intention is to simply compare the `DateTime` with a least count of `second`, then you can do this

```
if ((dtpFromDate.Value.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond) > 
     (dtpToDate.Value.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond))
{
   MessageBox.Show("From Date is greater than To Date");
   return;
}
```

The `DateTime` object has a least count of a `Tick`. You can read up on [DateTime.Ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_fields(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth
>   of a second. There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond, or 10 million
>   ticks in a second.

Answer (score 0):

I had two date time pickers on the same windows form. Even though I was making a comparison of dtpStartDate.Value.Date and dtpEndDate.Value.Date, the check for the end date being earlier than the start date was still coming up wrong when it appeared that the two date time picker values were the same. It wasn't until I compared the values down to the millisecond like `dtpEndDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")` and `dtpStartDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")` that I saw the difference.

In my case I wanted to only compare month, day and year. What I had to do to make a proper comparison was use

```
if (dtpStartDate.Value.Date.Date > dtpEndDate.Value.Date.Date)
        {
            // Start Date cannot be later than the End Date
        }
```